# Domain Entity and UI Entity

Tags: user-interface, dns, entity, layer

We are creating a project using MVC with C#  in application with having following layers:

- Presentation (MVC)

  - Controller
  - View
- Domain

  - Domain Entity
  - Repository interface
  - Interface for unit of works
- Infrastructure (DataAccess)

  - Repository
  - Unit of works
  - Edmx
  - Data Entity

Our Domain Entity and data entity is same. It is POCO class. We have bound our views with domain entity that are tightly coupled.

Question:

1. Is this correct or we will create a ViewModel entity for our views?

2. Will we pass our data entity to our view so that we will save on mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is rigth... Talking about MVC, our layers meens MODEL, VIEW,CONTROLLER, maybe